# Result of my implementation of memset only prints the changes, and not the entire result string

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att, memset

This is the same implementation experiment from [memset movq giving segfault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60500775/memset-movq-giving-segfault)
I've been printing out memset's result, and it seems to only print out the change, and not the rest of the string as well.

```
experimentMemset:   #memset(void *ptr, int value, size_t num)

    movq %rdi, %rax     #sets rax to the first pointer, to return later

.loop:
        cmp $0, %edx    #see if num has reached limit
        je .end                

        movq %rsi, (%rdi)       #copies value into rdi
        inc %rdi                #increments pointer to traverse string
        subl $1, %edx   #decrements count
        jmp .loop
.end:
        ret



int main {

 char str[] = "almost every programmer should know memset!";
    printf("MEMSET\n");
    my_memset(str, '-', 6);
    printf("%s\n", str);

}
```

my output: ------

correct output from cplusplus.com:  ------ every programmer should know memset!

Comment: `movq %rsi, (%rdi)` writes 8 bytes, not 1 as you want it to.

Comment: You probably want `movb %sil, (%rdi)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`movq` is storing the high zeros in `int value`, not just the low byte.  This terminates the C string.**  And also writing past the end of the ptr+length your caller passes!

Use `mov %sil, (%rdi)` to store 1 byte.

(In fact you're storing 8 bytes with `movq`, including the high 4 bytes that according to the calling convention are allowed to contain garbage because they're not part of the 32-bit `int value`.  With this caller they'll also be zero, though.)

**You could have detected this by examining memory contents with a debugger or better test harness**.  Do that next time.  A better caller for debugging would have used `write` or `fwrite` to print the full buffer, and you could pipe that into `hexdump -C`.  Or just use GDB's `x` command to dump bytes of memory.

---

**You only check `%edx`, the low 4 bytes of `size_t num` in `%rdx`**.  If you caller asks you to set exactly 4GiB of memory, you'll return without storing anything.

---

You can make the loop more compact by putting the conditional branch at the bottom.  You could change the declaration to `unsigned num`, or you could fix your code.

```
.globl experimentMemset
experimentMemset:   #memset(void *ptr, int value, size_t num)

    movq %rdi, %rax     #sets rax to the first pointer, to return later

    test  %rdx, %rdx    # special case: size = 0, loop runs zero times
    jz    .Lend
.Lloop:                   # do{
      mov   %sil, (%rdi)     # store the low byte of int value
      inc   %rdi             # ++ptr
      dec   %rdx
      jnz  .Lloop         # }while(--count);
.Lend:
    ret
```

It's not even any more instructions: I just pulled the cmp/jcc out of the loop to make it a skip-the-loop check, and turns the `jmp` at the bottom into `jcc` that reads the flags set by `dec`.

---

### Efficiency

Of course storing 1 byte at a time is very inefficient, even if we optimize the loop so more CPUs can run it at 1 iteration per clock.  For medium-sized arrays hot in cache, modern CPUs can go 32 to 64 times faster using AVX or AVX512 stores.  And can go close to that fast for aligned buffers with `rep stosb` string instructions, on CPUs that have the ERMSB feature.  Yes, x86 has a single instruction that implements `memset`!

(Or for wider patterns, `wmemset` with `rep stosd`.  On CPUs without ERMSB but with fast strings (PPro and later before IvyBridge), `rep stosd` or stosq is faster so you might `imul $0x01010101, %esi, %eax` to broadcast the low byte.)

```
# slowish for small or misaligned buffers
# but probably still better than a byte loop for buffers larger than maybe 16 bytes
.globl memset_ermsb
memset_ermsb:   #memset(void *ptr, int value, size_t num)

    mov  %rdx, %rcx            # count = num
    mov  %esi, %eax            # AL = char to set
    rep  stosb                 # destination = RDI 
    ret
```

Real memset implementations use SIMD loops because that's faster for small or misaligned buffers.  Much has been written about optimizing memset / memcpy.  Glibc's implementations are pretty clever and a good example.

Kernel code can't use FPU/SIMD easily so `rep stos` memset and `rep movsb` memcpy does get used in real life in the Linux kernel.